# Does Bonobo git server support web hooks

Tags: bonobo

I would like to set up a Git server on a Windows server using open source code.  Bonobo is one of my alternatives, but I can't find information on the support for web hooks.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is - Yes!  For an example, see this description of how to use a post receive webhook to trigger a Jenkins build - https://blog.dangl.me/archive/configure-git-hooks-on-bonobo-git-server-in-windows/